# Representation of functional/distribution through infinte series of delta distributions possible?

Tags: distribution-theory, functional-calculus

Sorry, I am an engineer and this surpasses completely my math education. If I am not precise, please comment on open/unclear assumptions, and I will do my best in correcting my mistakes.

**QUESTION:** is it possible to represent an integral $\lambda$ (functional with characteristic function $g(x)$) over the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ with unknown/arbitrary real valued function $f(x)$

\begin{equation}
\lambda = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f(x) dx \ ,
\end{equation}

and not specified but normalized, non-negative weight function $g(x)$ (not necessarily continuous)

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) dx = 1 \ , \qquad
g(x) \geq 0 \quad \forall x \ ,
\end{equation}

in terms of Dirac distributions as follows?

\begin{equation}
\lambda
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) f(x) dx
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i \delta(x_i - x) f(x) dx
= \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i f(x_i)
\end{equation}

If yes, then is the characteristic function $g(x)$ (not necessarily constinuous) representable as

\begin{equation}
g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i \delta(x_i - x) \ , \quad 
\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i = 1 \ , \quad
c_i \geq 0 \quad \forall i
\end{equation}

for the functional $\lambda$?

Any recommendations for literature (standard books) for this would also be helpful. Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**
Can this be interpreted in the sense of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals and corresponding convergent series? I just thought of this with $dG = g dx$

\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda
&=& \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) g(x) dx \\
&=& \int_{\mathbb{R}} f dG \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i) (G(x_{i+1}) - G(x_i)) 
= \sum_{i=1}^\infty f(x_i) \Delta G_i \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \delta(x_i - x) dx \Delta G_i
= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \left[ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \Delta G_i \delta(x_i - x) \right]  dx
\end{eqnarray}

So I dont know if this is correct

\begin{equation}
g(x)
= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \Delta G_i \delta(x_i - x)
\end{equation}